# What is the "mixpanel" exactly?

Tags: html, frontend, mixpanel

I just create pure site and mt ghostery found "mixpanel" on my site.But i never added this feature to my code, so why it is on my site?How to delete this feature?

Comment: You have to describe the context better. What kind of site is it (technical), where do you find mixpanel, etc? Provide more details

Comment: Simple HTML + CSS site made with Bootstrap framework.When i go to site Ghostery extension find 1 tracker on this site - "Mixpanel".But i never add some special code to my site (if i want to, i will use google tracker).I want to remove it from my site, but i do not understand properly what kind of thing this "Mixtpanel" is.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what Mixpanel is, but it might be some installed chrome extension that is giving you this error in the dev tools. => try opening it up in a incognito page and have a look to see if it's still there.